# why ToDoubleBiFunction doesn't extend BiFunction

Tags: java

I wonder why [ToDoubleBiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToDoubleBiFunction.html) doesn't extend [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html). Just how I did:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyToDoubleBiFunction<Integer, Integer> f = (a, b) -> a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
    System.out.println(f.apply(1, 2));
  }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface MyToDoubleBiFunction<T, U> extends BiFunction<T, U, Double> {
}
```

This code works and prints `3.0`.

Also what is the point of using wordy `applyAsDouble` method instead of well-known `apply`?

Comment: The result type of `MyToDoubleBiFunction.apply` is `Double` whereas it is `double` for `ToDoubleBiFunction.applyAsDouble`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of specific versions of `BiFunction` such as `ToDoubleBiFunction` is to avoid [auto(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) - in this case, autoboxing / -unboxing a primitive `double` value to / from a `java.lang.Double` object.

If `ToDoubleBiFunction` would extend `BiFunction<T, U, Double>` then you'd have auto(un)boxing.

Note that you cannot use primitive types as type arguments in Java, so `BiFunction<T, U, double>` (note that `double` is the primitive type here) is not possible.

Comment: Nice, concrete, and efficient answer. +1 from me. What I'm wondering (without diving to the source code) how WE can write the `Function` without auto(un)boxing with three, four, or more parameters? e.g. `ToIntThreeFunction`...

Comment: @zlakad there's nothing magical: you just define an interface with a single method, returning an `int`: `interface ToIntThreeFunction<A, B, C> { int apply3(A a, B b, C c); }`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, ah, well, I'll try to that. TY.